# if(a == b) doesn't work for doubles in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am at the moment trying to code a titration curve simulator. But I am running into some trouble with comparing two values.

I have created a small working example that perfectly replicates the bug that I encounter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a, b;
    a = 5;
    b = 0;
    for(double i = 0; i<=(2*a); i+=0.1){
        b = i;
        cout << "a=" << a << "; b="<<b;
        if(a==b)
            cout << "Equal!" << endl;
        else
            cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output at the relevant section is

```
a=5; b=5
```

However, if I change the iteration increment from `i+=0.1` to `i+=1` or `i+=0.5` I get an output of

```
a=5; b=5Equal!
```

as you would expect.

I am compiling with g++ on linux using no further flags and I am frankly at a loss how to solve this problem. Any pointers (or even a full-blown solution to my problem) are very appreciated.

Comment: [Click me](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Don't use floating points in loop conditions...

Comment: This is not a good way to compare [floating-point numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: I will read through the link given by maroun maroun, I already thought it would come down to something like this. Thanks for the pointer! :)

Comment: Been asked a gazillion times...

Comment: `1.0` and `0.5` can be represented as finite, exact numbers, using floating point numbers. `0.1` on the other hand can only be represented by an infinite floating point number, which exposes a rounding error when stored in a finite floating point number.

Comment: This: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The Goldberg paper is generally overkill (I have never read all of it, and don't intend to!).  http://floating-point-gui.de is a basic summary of the issues.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth From the front page of http://floating-point-gui.de/: "Maybe you asked for help on some forum and got pointed to a [long article with lots of formulas](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) that didn’t seem to help with your problem." - guess where that link points to ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike integers, multiplying floats/doubles and adding them up doesn't produce **exactly** the same results.

So the best practice is find if the `abs` of their difference is small enough.

If you have some idea on the size of the numbers, you can use a constant:

```
if (fabs(a - b) < EPS) // equal
```

If you don't (much slower!):

```
float a1 = fabs(a), b1 = fabs(b);
float mn = min(a1,b1), mx = max(a1,b1);
if (mn / mx > (1- EPS)) // equal
```

Note:
In your code, you can use `std::abs` instead. Same for `std::min/max`. The code is clearer/shorter when using the C functions.

Comment: Why not use `std::abs`? It's overloaded for floating point types in C++.

Comment: std::abs is also fine. Code was a little shorter in the answer with `fabs` - just for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is... interesting. Testing equality is annoying with floats/doubles in most languages because it is [impossible to accurately represent many numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) in IEEE floating point math. Basically, where you might compute an expression to be 5.0, the compiler might compute it to be 4.9999999, because it's the closest representable number in the IEEE standard.

Because these numbers *are* slightly different, you end up with an inequality. Because it's unmaintainble to try and predict which number you will see at compile time, you can't/shouldn't attempt to hard code either one of them into your source to test equality with. As a hard rule, avoid directly checking equality of floating point numbers.

Instead, test that they are *extremely close* to being equal with something like the following:

```
template<typename T>
bool floatEqual(const T& a, const T& b) {
  auto delta = a * 0.03;
  auto minAccepted = a - delta;
  auto maxAccepted = a + delta;
  return b > minAccepted && b < maxAccepted;
}
```

This checks whether b is within a range of + or - 3% of the value of a.

Comment: [IEEE 754 floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) arithmetic is well defined, and is predictable on all implementations that implement the standard (most C++ compilers do).

Comment: @IInspectable - intriguing. Thanks! I'm more interested in the result than the reason, but I've updated the post all the same.

Comment: Bad example: 5.0 _is_ representable in IEEE 754. 4.9999999 is not. The question contains another non-representable number, 0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend restructuring your loop to iterate using integers and then converting the integers into doubles, like this:

```
double step = 0.1;

for(int i = 0; i*step<=2*a; ++i){
    b = i*step;
    cout << "a=" << a << "; b="<<b;
    if(a==b)
        cout << "Equal!" << endl;
    else
        cout << endl;
}
```

This still isn't perfect.  You possibly have some loss of precision in the multiplication; however, the floating point errors don't accumulate like they do when iterating using floating point values.