# Is it valid to compare double directly using ==?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-point-comparison

I always compares `double`s like

```cpp
double a = xxx, b = xxx;
if (fabs(a-b)< 1e5) ...
```

But I read some codes, they just use

```cpp
if (a == b) ...
```

So is it valid to use `==` directly when comparing `double`s? And I don't care the accuracy issue.

Comment: It is valid, but due to rounding errors, two things that should be equal might not be. So it's generally not recommended. For example `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` will yield false.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with comparing two double.

Comment: [if(a == b) doesn't work for doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939420/ifa-b-doesnt-work-for-doubles-in-a-for-loop) and [is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Once you read/understand the answers given in the dupes, you'll automatically be able to answer your question which is that yes it is valid but not recommended due to the reasons mentioned in the dupes.

Comment: Generally, it's more preferable to compare floating point numbers with some tolerance - it almost always give you the result you'd expect. But there is nothing wrong to compare them via `==`, if you know, that these numbers are exactly the same in floating point representation.

Comment: If it's the same `double` value (copied between variables, restored from storage...), it is safe. If it is the same number resulting from some independent calculation, it is not safe.

Comment: It is complicated. Even more than compiring with fabs/epsilon value), to give you an idea : [Comparing Floating Point Numbers, 2012 Edition](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/). So how you actually need to "losely" compare is very use case specific (are all your numbers close to 1.0, or much larger etc. etc.)

Comment: What does “And I don't care the accuracy issue” mean? If `a` and `b` would have been equal if computed with real-number arithmetic but are not equal because of floating-point rounding, you do not care what answer you get?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Floating point types are implementation defined so there's no guarantee that 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 is false. It might yield true on some platforms even though it's usually (typically) false. Even on systems where it is usually false, changes in optimizations and/or other settings, the expression itself, or even versions of the compiler can potentially change the result.

Comment: With whole numbers (well within the significand representation) `double a = 1.0, b = 2.0, c = 3.0; if (a + b == c) cout << "equal\n";` will **always** be true.  But change that to `double a = 0.1, b = 0.2, c = 0.3;` and it *might* not be true, and some people find that surprising / disturbing / upsetting / confusing and possibly offensive to one's math sensibilities.

Comment: `fabs(a-b)< 1e5` is a poor alternative for comparing _nearness_.